# Consume a QAAWS with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-2010, wsdl

I been given a QAAWS and I need to pull out the data from it. For privacy issues I cannot give you the QAAWS but it is the same as [this](https://liveoffice.etosoftware.com/dswsbobje/qaawsservices/biws?WSDL=1&cuid=AbCz8IZ1FRxJgxT3v7b0XYA) one.

I added the wsdl as a service reference, but I am not sure how to get the data since I have to enter the login and password. I can use SOAPUI and obtain an XML file that I can use but I want to make the process more automatic where I use the QAAWS with my website.

I haven't had any luck searching any good tutorials or guides. Has anyone dealt with these services before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. In Visual Studio 10 create a new Console Application
2. Next add a web reference and use the web service WSDL URL given to you.
3. On the `program.cs` file write the following code (*`TestWeb` here is the name of your Web Reference.*):

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using
   ConsoleApplication1.TestWeb;
   namespace ConsoleApplication1
       {
       class Program
           {
           static void Main(string[] args)
               {
               ConsoleApplication1.TestWeb.TestService test1 = new 
               ConsoleApplication1.TestWeb.TestService();
               String message, creatorname, creationdateformatted, description, universe;
               DateTime creationdate;
               int queryruntime, fetchedrows;
               ConsoleApplication1.TestWeb.Row[] row = test1.runQueryAsAService("<cms username>", "<password>", out message, out creatorname, out creationdate, out    creationdateformatted, out description, out universe, out queryruntime , out fetchedrows);
               int resultCount = row.Length;
               Console.WriteLine("Message = " + message);
               Console.WriteLine("Creator Name = " + creatorname);
               Console.WriteLine("Creation Date = " + creationdate.ToString());
               Console.WriteLine("Creation Date Formatted = " + creationdateformatted);
               Console.WriteLine("Description = " + description);
               Console.WriteLine("Universe = " + universe);
               Console.WriteLine("Query Run Time = " + queryruntime);
               Console.WriteLine("Fetched Rows = " + fetchedrows);
               for (int i = 0; i < resultCount; i++)
                   {
                   Console.WriteLine(row[i].ShipperID + "  " + row[i].CompanyName + " " + row[i].Phone);
                   }
               Console.Read();
               }
           }
       }
   ```

The `username` and the `password` can be written into the code if you want. This is originally from this [page](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/70094744-4144-2f10-64a1-f2e4f74e282a?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true&53824530166488). I tested it against my own Web Service and it worked.